# Cannot find module '@material-ui/core'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I had a problem with importing "@material-ui/core" to my react/typescript/webpack app. Always when I ran

`webpack --config webpack.config.js`

it failed with error

`Cannot find module '@material-ui/core'`

The same error was also underlined in the Visual Studio Code.

My index.tsx looked like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
    return <Button>Hi dudes</Button>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `tsconfig.json` as below

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "module": "ES6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

`allowJs` made it importable and other fixed webpack build.

Comment: Setting `allowJs` to true did not work for me.

Comment: I just fixed my issue my setting `"moduleResolution": "node"` in my tsconfig file

Answer (score 8):

`yarn add @material-ui/core` or `npm i @material-ui/core` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: It did not for me. I had @material-ui in node_modules and still not able to compile, even if I added direct path to webpack config

Comment: Have you tried deleting and installing the node modules again ?

Comment: Yes :) All was there and ready, just reference could not be obtained. My solution above helped.

Comment: That issue was due to the installation or we have to manually change it every time to fix the error ?

Comment: Just set properly webpack config and u are fine :)

Answer (score 2):

- `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`
- `yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just incase someone else is battling with this in 2023 and all of the above solutions did not work. This is what worked for me:

The error message you're seeing is because the package @material-ui/styles is not installed in your project.

Follow these steps to install it:
Run the following from the root directory of your project(where you have package.json):

`npm install @material-ui/core` or `yarn add @material-ui/core`

```
npm install @material-ui/core
npm install @material-ui/styles
```

or

```
yarn add @material-ui/core`
yarn add @material-ui/styles
```

NB: If like me you get the error message on your terminal after trying to run the above code, please run them again, and add the --force flag to them like this:

npm install @material-ui/styles --force

Answer (score 0):

Check your Material UI documentation you're using.
Recently, this:

`import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";`

got replaced by:

`import { Button } from "@mui/material";`

MUI Site may show you older examples, try switching documentation version on the website.

Here's v5 Grid:

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/

And here's v4 Grid:

https://v4.mui.com/components/grid/

The imports differ among these versions.